# Querying for multiple file versions using Test-Path

Tags: powershell

I want it to query version of several files using multi-host text file then output to CSV.  If I only enter one `$filename` variable in the `$filepath` variable, then it works.  Just can't put `$filename`, `$filename1`, and `$filename2`.

```
$filename = "\Windows\System32\browser.dll"
$filename1 = "\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\setpoint.exe"
$filename2 = "\Program Files\MAGIX\Photostory Deluxe\2018\Fotos_dlx.exe"

$obj = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 

$computernames = Get-Content C:\Temp\computers.txt 
foreach ($computer in $computernames) 
{ 
$filepath = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\$filename,$filename1,$filename2" 

if ($filepath -eq "True") { 
$file = Get-Item "\\$computer\c$\$filename" 


        $obj += New-Object psObject -Property @{'Computer'=$computer;'FileVersion'=$file.VersionInfo|Select FileVersion} 
        } 
     } 

$obj | select computer, FileVersion | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Temp\File_Results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: be sure to vote if one of the answers was the one that helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

`Test-Path` will accept an array of files to test, but you aren't building the array correctly. First put all the file paths you want to test in an array

```
$filename = "\Windows\System32\browser.dll"
$filename1 = "\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\setpoint.exe"
$filename2 = "\Program Files\MAGIX\Photostory Deluxe\2018\Fotos_dlx.exe"
$filesToTest = @($filename, $filename1, $filename2)
```

Then later, you can test each:

```
$filesExist = $filesToTest | foreach {Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\$_"}
```

`$filesExist` contains an array of booleans so you can just check to make sure they're all true:

```
if($filesExist -notcontains $false)
     #get the file info
```

Comment: I tried this but  still not able to query the file version for all variables, just $filename.  I think it has to do with this line:   if ($filepath -eq "True") { 
$file = Get-Item "\\$computer\c$\$filename"   The get-item line has just $filename.   Trying to output the 3 file versions to a CSV containing 2 columns.  One for computer name the next one for file versoin

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a ForEach to process the array of files,
but you can maintain a boolean end result by anding the current Test-Path:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SO_53452648.ps1
$filename = "\Windows\System32\browser.dll"
$filename1 = "\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\setpoint.exe"
$filename2 = "\Program Files\MAGIX\Photostory Deluxe\2018\Fotos_dlx.exe"
$filesToTest = @($filename, $filename1, $filename2)

Clear-Variable filesExist -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Computer = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME

$filesToTest | ForEach-Object {
    "{0,5} Test-Path {1}" -f (Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\$_"),"\\$computer\c$\$_"
    $filesexist = $filesexist -and (Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\$_")
}
"="*40
"{0,5} filesexist on {1}" -f $filesexist,$computer
```

Sample output.

```
> Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SO_53452648.ps1
 True Test-Path \\HP-G1610\c$\\Windows\System32\browser.dll
 True Test-Path \\HP-G1610\c$\\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\setpoint.exe
False Test-Path \\HP-G1610\c$\\Program Files\MAGIX\Photostory Deluxe\2018\Fotos_dlx.exe
========================================
False filesexist on HP-G1610
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter is simpler?

```
$found = true ; $filepath = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\$filename", "$filename1" , "$filename2" | % {$found = $found -and $_ }
```

Test-Path does accept an array of file names and you can enter it much as you started out in your example.  This is a single-line example and some purists may suggest using `ForEach-Object` in place of `%`.

Alternately you could possibly simplify by using the `-notContains` syntax suggested by @zdan.

Comment: do you know if I can do something similar with the Get-Item line I have above?  I'm trying to query the file version for All variables and output to CSV in columns.  The Get-item line only works for one variable, $filename.  Trying to find a way to query all the variables using Get-Item.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Maybe a code example of what you're trying to do would clear up my confusion.

Comment: my goal is to populate a CSV with the computer names and file versions of all the files that I'm querying.  In my code above it's 3 so far.  However, when I run the code it only calls the first variable, $filename and populates jus that in my CSV.  I want it to call all 3 and then populate my CSV with the versions.  I think the problem is in the Get-item since it calls only $filename.  Here is the line: 

if($filesExist -notcontains $false) {
$file = Get-Item "\\$computer\c$\$filename"